# restart if element isn't found after time SELENIUM

Tags: python, selenium

I use 'Selenium' to scrape websites. Sometimes websites will not finish loading due to several different reasons. If I the element hasn't appeared within 10 seconds, I want to close the browser and restart the loop.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
try:
  wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.top")))
except TimeoutException:
  driver.quit()
  continue
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I thought the `wait.until` would throw a `TimeoutException` as described [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp).

Comment: What actually happens when you run this code? Also you might want to try reloading the page rather than closing the browser?

Comment: How do I know that the element will be there if I just reload the page? When I run this code the script can end up waiting for a page to load for ever.

Comment: Are u sure the indentation is correct?

Comment: Yeah, the indentation above was wrong but it is correct.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show us a bit more code, including the loop, so we can see that the loop logic is correct. Also please clarifiy whether the element is actually on the page or not when your code waits forever.

Comment: Are you sure the code fails in the `wait.until`? put `print 1` before and after  the `wait.until` to make sure it even arrives there when the code fails.

Comment: whats error you are getting

Comment: try to share few lines of code

Comment: How `TimeoutException` is imported?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are waiting for a wrong exception, try:

```
expect NoSuchElementException:
```